# How to configure url rewriting in IIS6 to consider url ending with "/" like a page?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6

I'm working on Windows Server2003 with the following:

> IIS6
>   .NET Runtime 2.0
>   ASP.NET C#

I've got some pages like these:

```
fr.mywebsite.eu/productA/sub_product1.html  
fr.mywebsite.eu/productA/sub_product2.html  

fr.mywebsite.eu/productB/sub_product14.html  
fr.mywebsite.eu/productC/sub_product26.html
```

The directories `productA`, `productB`, `productC` don't really exist.

In my `global asax`, I get the url requested and I do something like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(
    "product.aspx?p=" + codeProduct + "&sp=" + codeSubProduct);
```

For now everything is working.

But I'm trying to make the following page list all subproducts:

`http://fr.mywebsite.eu/productB/`

The problem is that IIS considers `productB` to be a directory and I get a `404` error.

Is there any directive to make IIS not check if **DIRECTORY** exist similar to the manner of ISAPI extensions but for a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find the issue. I had to insert a wildcard application maps to 
\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
don't check if the file exist.

Answer (score -1):

If you have admin access to the server, use http://iirf.codeplex.com/ which will do this and much more (for free) without even involving ASP...